# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop... but it does have an a key prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with key prop error in SummaryListItem Component.
Console shows me errors despite the fact, that underlined component DOES have an key prop with unigue ID.

```
{SIXTH_STEP_DATA.map(({ text, id }, index) => (
        <CardWrapper elevation={1} key={id}>
          <SummaryListItem
            info={info}
            key={id}
            handleSetStep={handleSetStep}
            viewContent={viewContent}
            text={text}
            index={index}
            timeIntervalInMiliseconds={timeIntervalInMiliseconds}
          />
        </CardWrapper>
      ))}
```

[image]

I tried to add also a dynamic id to another list wrapped inside this component (useId hook) but its also didnt helped.

```
<Card>
      <Divider />
      <StyledCardContent>
        <StyledList disablePadding>
          <StyledListItem disableGutters key={keyId}>
            {viewContent ? (
              <StyledLink variant='h4' onClick={() => handleSetStep(index + 1)}>
                {t(text)}
              </StyledLink>
            ) : (
              <Typography variant='h4'>{t(text)}</Typography>
            )}
          </StyledListItem>
          <ListItemAvatar>
            {viewContent ? (
              <LabelWrapper>{compileContent(summaryInfo)}</LabelWrapper>
            ) : (
              <AvatarWrapperSuccess>
                <Fade in={opacity} timeout={500}>
                  <CheckIcon />
                </Fade>
              </AvatarWrapperSuccess>
            )}
          </ListItemAvatar>
        </StyledList>
      </StyledCardContent>
    </Card>
```

Wheres the issue ? I am pretty sure that component is given a proper key with id. This is the first time when this solution didnt worked.

EDIT : adding id from useId hook for SummaryListIteam instead of id used for CardWrapper also didnt helped :/ Strange.

Comment: are you certain your `id` is unique?

Comment: Both, `CardWrapper ` and `SummaryListItem` have the same `key={id}`. If this is not a problem, then at least it may be confusing. Try to prefix the id's someting like `key={\`SummaryListItem-${id}\`}` so they don't collide.

Comment: Adding to the other comments - it may be sufficient to have the key only on the parent/root element in that loop. The children don't need have a key unless they are in a loop themselves. This is probably confusing a the renderer as there will be 2 elements with the same key for every element in that list

Comment: Checked both sugestion. Deleting key on child will still get error if i have prop key only at CardWrapper.
Tried to add id from useId() hook on SummaryListItem. Also didnt not work.
Confusing as hell.

Answer (score -2):

[Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8e63.png)

You need to use a unique property (like index, id, slug, unique random number).

```
{list.map((name, index) => (
    <Name key={index}>
      <h2 >
        {name}
      </h2>
    </Name>
  ))}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).